# Print warning if db is out sync with code

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, orm, typeorm

Using TypeORM for node/typescript:

If we have this:

```js
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  // ...
  synchronize: false, // Recommended for production
  migrations: ['path/to/your/migrations/*.ts'], // Specify your migrations directory
});
```

if the db is out of sync with the code, is there a way to get a warning?

For mongodb, this would basically only be for indexes since collections don't have column types. But for SQL-based DBs, I guess it would require diffing the generated SQL? Which might not be straightforward.